# What's the reason to omit "else" in "if else" condition?

Tags: php

What's the reason for writing this code:

```php
if ($everything === "ok") {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

... instead of this code:

```php
if ($everything === "ok") {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

...?

Comment: It is shorter :)

Comment: There's no need for an `else` because if `$everything === "ok"` the function will exit (`return true;`) and the `return false;` statement can never be reached. Thus the `return false` will only be executed if `$everything !== "ok"` which is exactly the same as putting it in an `else` clause.

Comment: there is no need for `if` either when boolean is to be returned. It is equivalent to `return $everything === "ok";`

Comment: @GáborBakos this is just a simplified example of `if-then` condition. Replace it with anything more complicated so that `if-then` makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific reason behind it write it this way. It's just short version of the former one to later ones. All of them are doing same thing with decreasing some sort of typing nothing else.

**Easy to understand**

```
if ($everything === "ok") {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

**Shorter**

```
if ($everything === "ok") {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

**Shortest**

```
return (isset($everything) && $everything === "ok") ? true:false;
```

***May be other ways are also possible to make more shorter.***